# Can a java class member variable decleared as `native`?

Tags: java, native, keyword

For instance, is the following legal?

```
public class Foo {
  private native int bar;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What behavior would you expect from a "native" variable?

Comment: Seriously,  Its a pretty straightforward question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**.
You could've tried this and the compiler would've complained.

Comment: Give an example, would you? I can recall NetBeans doing it, but haven't caught Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse might warn you, or might show a warning as an error if you've configured it to do so ... but this is all up to you configuring Eclipse to be overly cautious.

Comment: Replace "Eclipse" by "javac" and the answer is a bit more robust.

Comment: yes, Matt, but do you think the author of the question has configured his Eclipse? :)

Answer (score 2):

Sooner or later the folks out there will start asking on SO where their car keys are on.

And this is everything but fun. I mean, come on, writing the above code in Notepad, saving it as a .java file* and running `javac` over it should have taken less than posting over here.

***** Enclose the name of the file between `"` as in "OurFirstEverNotepadJavaUnitTheGreatNativeTest.java", otherwise you'll get a (kernel) panic attack once you'll see it gets saved as .java.txt

Answer (score 2):

As has been said answer is no.

You can only apply native to methods.

Native modifier indicates that the implementation of the method exists elsewhere, maybe in a library outside the JVM, even implemented in a non-Java language